# PHP: preserving desired value in array

Tags: php, arrays

How do I specify the array value to keep and throw everything else out?

```
$want_to_keep = 32

Array
(
    [1015] => 78
    [2316] => 78
    [5374] => 32
    [8913] => 78
    [1397] => 32
)
```

I only want items with '32' values, so output:

```
Array
(
    [5374] => 32
    [1397] => 32
)
```

I looked at `array_filter` and `array_intersect`, both of which doesn't suit this need.

Comment: Why does `array_filter()` not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace the array with a filtered one:

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($value) use ($want_to_keep) {
    return $value === $want_to_keep;
});
```

A stranger way:

```
$arr = array_fill_keys(array_keys($arr, $want_to_keep, true), $want_to_keep);
```

Comment: thanks for all the answers but I thought this answer was most elegant.

Comment: @user1899415 Ya, this works, but php's array_intersect() is built in and does exactly what you want. Why not just use that?

Comment: @MarkM The `array_intersect()` has an additional sorting overhead that this solution doesn't have.

Comment: @Jack Ok, fair enough. I did some testing and it seems you are correct - your solution is faster. Well played, sir.

Comment: @MarkM What's more interesting is that both our answers showed that `array_filter()` as well as `array_intersect()` can be used even though OP didn't think they would be "suitable".

Answer (score 3):

try to make new array with 32 values

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if ($v == '32') {
    $newarr[$k] = $v;
  }
}
print_r($newarr);
```

Want to same array try `unset()` like

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
  if ($v != '32') {
    unset($arr[$k]);
  }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: @Jack i agree with you but i have tried it on my end ok let me update this

Answer (score 3):

[**array_intersect()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) does exactly this.

Simply:

```
$want_to_keep = array(32);

$arr = Array
(
    1015 => 78,
    2316 => 78,
    5374 => 32,
    8913 => 78,
    1397 => 32
);

print_r(array_intersect($arr, $want_to_keep));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [5374] => 32
    [1397] => 32
)
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://codepad.org/MxdLlbPd)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to remove all the unwanted items

```
foreach($inputArray as $currItem=>$currValue)
{
if($currValue!=$desiredValue)
unset($inputArray($desiredValue);
}
```

where the variables names are implicit of their meaning.

Answer (score 1):

```
$want_to_keep = 32


$array = array_filter($array, function($element) use($want_to_keep) {
    return $element === $want_to_keep;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would usw.

```
$keys = array_keys($arrToSearch, 32);
$new = [];
foreach($keys AS $key){
       $new[$key] = $arrToSearch[$key];
}
unset($arrayToSearch);

 //what you requsted is
 $new;
```

Comment: Not a Problem added the keys

Comment: This is the second part of my answer, but using 5 lines instead of 1 :)

Comment: unser($arrayToSearch); ?

Comment: The unset is for removing the old array of we dont need it